# grep + changing values in vector in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a two-variable data frame `data` containing `VariableA` & `VariableB`. Both columns are of the character class. What I would like to do is grep Variable A for elements with capital letters. Then, with the rows containing those elements I would like to change the Foos in Column B with "Yes". The `grep` part works fine:

```
data <- data.frame(VariableA = c("A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d"),VariableB=  c("Foo", "Foo","Foo", "Foo","Foo","Foo","Foo","Foo"))
grep("[A-Z]", data$VariableA)
```

This returns an integer string containing all of the row numbers where there are capital letters. Is there a way to then change the values of `VariableB` only for those with capital letters in a single call? Without subsetting and merging a bunch of times?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: No problem, but update the question tag set to include `R` as well.

Comment: How do you want to change the values in `VariableB`?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: See the code for reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited to use code provided in the question]

Here's how I would do it. This changes the values in column B and rows where A contains a capital letter.

```
# Create data frame, keep strings as strings
data <- data.frame(VariableA = c("A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d"),VariableB=  c("Foo", "Foo","Foo", "Foo","Foo","Foo","Foo","Foo"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# A single call to change column B when column A contains a capital letter
data[grep("[A-Z]", data$VariableA), "VariableB"] <- "newFoo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index vector created by `grep` in the function `replace` to change the values in `VariableB`:

```
idx <- grep("[A-Z]", data$VariableA)
data$VariableB <- replace(as.character(data$VariableB), idx, "Yes")
```

This command replaced the values in `VariableB` with `"ABC"` if there's an uppercase letter in `VariableA`. Note that you have to convert the factor `VariableB` to a character vector.